# wcf pollingduplex connection limit in silverlight 3.0

Tags: wcf, silverlight, duplex

I have build a silverlight application for message service. my problem is silverlight application **disconnect after 10 connection**. But i want it unlimited or thousands. I have spent a lot of time on this problem. some point about my application as:

1. I have build 3 prject like silverlight project, web project, wcf service project.
2. Im using PollingDuplexHttpBinding in wcf.that configure with we.bconfig.
3. In silverlight project i have add service refrence and create service object with pollingduplex binding.
4. I have configure web.config of wcf service project like :
5. I have test this project on iis6 server 2003 server but problem same.

please help me to sole this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the number of concurrent threads IIS can run (sounds like you have it configured to run 10 at the moment). You can increase that number through IIS configuration...but performance is going to suffer.

The problem is that Duplex Services hosted in IIS never release their threads...so every user connected to the service sucks up another IIS worker thread. Duplex performance has been discussed elsewhere, but the common tone is this:

IIS can not host scalable Duplex Services.

My suggestion would be to find another way to host those services (WCF outside IIS, Custom Web Server, etc.).

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Niessner
very nice. Thanks for your answer.
Then please sugest me wich binding is best for this application, NetMsmqBinding, BasicHttpBinding ot other.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that my PollingDuplex-software had limit of 10 clients when using one Internet Explorer. The limitation was still there with Windows 2008 Server R2 machine and Web.config having many settings:

for binding:  binding name="pollingDu​plexBinding" maxConnections=​"100"

for serviceBehaviors behaviour:  serviceThrottli​ng maxConcurrentCa​lls="1000" maxConcurrentIn​stances="1000" maxConcurrentSe​ssions="1000"

and for pollingDuplex  maxPendingSessi​ons="2147483647​" maxPendingMessa​gesPerSession="​2147483647"

But then when I tried with different clients:

- 6 clients on IE on server
- 6 clients on IE on a different client machine
- 4 clients on FireFox on this client machine

And it worked. So, there is some kind of limit with same client connections.